How to attach eBPF program right after IP table enforcement?
I am an eBPF newbie and writing IPv6 to IPv4 translation using eBPF, my eBPF program is attached eth0 interface (operating as BPF_PROG_TYPE_SCHED_ACT program type) and translate all the IPv6 to IPv4 on the ingress. The host runs a few applications that only listen on IPv4 sockets hence there is no IPv6 sockets available to attach to socket level injection point. The host do have some IP table rules to accept/reject incoming packets based on the IP/PORT. I want my eBPF program to run after the IP table enforcement but the current eBPF program runs before the IP table enforcement. Is there anyway I can make the eBPF program to execute after the IP table lookup?
Also, any pointers or reference to the linux network packet processing pipeline to know where the IP table lookups are handled and where the eBPF hooks are executed would be helpful for me to understand the IP table and eBPF relationship.
I tried attaching the eBPF program in XDP, BPF_PROG_TYPE_SCHED_CLS, and BPF_PROG_TYPE_SCHED_ACT, application don't have any IPv6 sockets so if I attach to IPv6 sockets then the eBPF program is not executed upon IPv6 packet arrival. I only need to translate for the IPv6 packets that are accepted by IP table rules this is where i need to make sure IP tables rules applied before it hits my eBPF program.
